# Effect of air signals over a cable

Tags: signal, noise

I want to know the effect of air signals (like am/fm radio signal) over my long wire (~100m long  ~6mm^2 diameter). If i use band pass filter at radio frequency, how much voltage noise can i observe due to air signals, when it is close to a radio station?

Comment: This depends on the specs of the band pass filter.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the wire, and more about the radio environment - how close are the transmitters, and more about your application. Is the radio signal a good thing, or interference, to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking on an oscilloscope? If yes, you really don't need to be that close to a radio station to see the signal in mV.

However, you're going to have an issue with 100m wire. Because radio waves are, well, waves.. antennas always need to be a factor of the frequency you intend to use. This is why antennas are typically called "half wave dipole" or "quarter wave" - they're built to the wavelength at a given frequency. An antenna picks up waves better by matching the incoming frequency, and by being "directive", not by sheer size.

At ~100m, you're close to the wavelength of amateur and some aviation radio band... but not AM/FM radio (100MHz). If you wanted to pick up 101.1FM, that wavelength is about 3m.

With just voltage on a matched antenna, your signal is going to be a few millivolts, even less after you get though an RLC circuit - you'll need an op-amp if you want to do anything with that signal.

Comment: I just what to get rid of the radio signal noise, due to I want to communicate by using frequency modulation in fm band, with such a cable. If it is like you say around mv, noise is negligible for my communication.
Thank you brother.